# Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4, phpstorm

I have created custom module, In that I have just override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` class to get the `getPrice()`. But it's returning an error Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object?

**my php code is:**

//controller

```
<?php
class Course_Mca_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

//block file

```
<?php    

class Course_Mca_Block_Products extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product
{
    public function getPrice()
    {
          return parent::getPrice();
    }
}
```

//web.phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getPrice() ?>
```

//layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mca_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mca/products" name="mca_mca" template="mca/web.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </mca_index_index>
</layout>
```

//Course_mca.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Course_Mca>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
            </depends>
        </Course_Mca>
    </modules>
</config>
```

//config.xml

```
<blocks>
<!-- it's not working -->
        <!-- <catalog>
              <rewrite>
                  <product>Course_Mca_Block_Products</product>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog>-->
<!-- it's working -->
            <mca>
               <class>Course_Mca_Block</class>
           </mca>
    </blocks>
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you include the web.phtml file? And what does get_class($this); say?

Comment: in layout.xml file I include the type=block_file and template=.phtml_file

Comment: could you maybe add the code in your answer?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl, see my code is updated

Comment: @AnnaVölkl, see code is updated.looking for my bug where it is?

Comment: where do you assign the product to the block under "mca_index_index"

Comment: @DavidManners, see inside the controller am assign? <block type="mca/products" template="mca/web.phtml"></block> is this wrong?

Comment: do you have a controller that for the mca index action? as the block will need to get a product from somewhere

Comment: @DavidManners,Yes I have. see updated my code.

Comment: then see Marius' answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Seems like you did not attach any product to your block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the original `getPrice` method.
It looks like this:

```
public function getPrice()
{
    return $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

Digging deeper you end up in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getProduct()` that looks like this:

```
public function getProduct()
{
    if (!$this->getData('product') instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
        if ($this->getData('product')->getProductId()) {
            $productId = $this->getData('product')->getProductId();
        }
        if ($productId) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            if ($product) {
                $this->setProduct($product);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->getData('product');
}
```

In your case `$this->getData('product')` return `null`, and since `null` is not an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` you enter the first `if` statement and it crashes on this line: `if ($this->getData('product')->getProductId()) {` because you cannot call `null->getProductId()`.

Any instance of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` makes sense if you attach a product to it. Considering your layout file, I can conclude that you are trying to use your block without any product.

Here is how your `Mca_IndexController::indexAction()` should look:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('mca_mca');
if ($block){
    $productId = 15;//for example
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);
    $block->setProduct($product);
}
$this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: I do the leg work you get the answer ;)

Comment: @DavidManners. Well...that happens. I've ran a few marathons myself in here just to finish second :).

Comment: @Marius, thank you working fine,but actually I override this in config.xml file given <catalog>
                  <rewrite>
                      <product>Course_Mca_Block_Products</product>
                  </rewrite>
              </catalog> this code it's not working.if I give  <mca>
                   <class>Course_Mca_Block</class>
               </mca> this code it's working. which one is correct?

Comment: @Marius, which one is correct? see in block section I have updated in my post.

Comment: @ManojKumar.Well...obviously the one that works is correct